# Editing Second Column in QTreeView with custom model Doesn't show editor

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I'm trying to make a QTreeView with a custom model and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the default editor to show in the second column. Shows fine in the first column

The underlying data in my custom model is nested OrderedDicts. The base OrderedDict is a special subclass `TupleKeyedOrderedDict` with the `__getitem__` method overridden to check if to see if the key is a tuple. If the key is a tuple, then the data structure is iterated through recursively until there are no more keys left.

The below example is a working example where the second column does not have a editor drawn, even though the data can be changed.

```py
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class TupleKeyedOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(sorted(kwargs.items()))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            item = self
            for k in key:
                if item != ():
                    item = item[k]
            return item
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            item = self
            previous_item = None
            for k in key:
                if item != ():
                    previous_item = item
                    item = item[k]
            previous_item[key[-1]] = value
        else:
            return super().__setitem__(key, value)

class SettingsModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.root = data
        self.my_index = {}   # Needed to stop garbage collection

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        if parent.isValid():
            index_pointer = parent.internalPointer()
            parent_dict = self.root[index_pointer]
        else:
            parent_dict = self.root
            index_pointer = ()
        row_key = list(parent_dict.keys())[row]
        child_pointer = (index_pointer, row_key)
        try:
            child_pointer = self.my_index[child_pointer]
        except KeyError:
            self.my_index[child_pointer] = child_pointer
        index = self.createIndex(row, column, child_pointer)
        return index

    def get_row(self, key):
        if key:
            parent = key[:-1]
            if not parent:
                return 0
            return list(self.root[parent].keys()).index(key[-1])
        else:
            return 0

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        child_key_list = index.internalPointer()
        if child_key_list:
            parent_key_list = child_key_list[:-1]
            try:
                parent_key_list = self.my_index[parent_key_list]
            except KeyError:
                self.my_index[parent_key_list] = parent_key_list
            return self.createIndex(self.get_row(parent_key_list), 0,
                                    parent_key_list)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if parent.column() > 0:
            return 0    # only keys have children, not values
        if parent.isValid():
            indexPtr = parent.internalPointer()
            parentValue = self.root[indexPtr]
            if isinstance(parentValue, OrderedDict):
                return len(self.root[indexPtr])
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return len(self.root)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 2  # Key & value

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if role in (QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
            indexPtr = index.internalPointer()
            if index.column() == 1:    # Column 1, send the value
                return self.root[indexPtr]
            else:                   # Column 0, send the key
                if indexPtr:
                    return indexPtr[-1]
                else:
                    return None
        else:  # Not display or Edit
            return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        pointer = self.my_index[index.internalPointer()]
        self.root[pointer] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid()
            return 0
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = TupleKeyedOrderedDict(**{'1': OrderedDict({'sub': 'b'}), '2': OrderedDict({'subsub': '3'})})

    model = SettingsModel(data)
    tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    tree_view.setModel(model)
    tree_view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with unpacking the tuple in the `index` method of `SettingsModel`

```py
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class TupleKeyedOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(sorted(kwargs.items()))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            item = self
            for k in key:
                if item != ():
                    item = item[k]
            return item
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            item = self
            previous_item = None
            for k in key:
                if item != ():
                    previous_item = item
                    item = item[k]
            previous_item[key[-1]] = value
        else:
            return super().__setitem__(key, value)

class SettingsModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.root = data
        self.my_index = {}   # Needed to stop garbage collection

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        if parent.isValid():
            index_pointer = parent.internalPointer()
            parent_dict = self.root[index_pointer]
        else:
            parent_dict = self.root
            index_pointer = ()
        row_key = list(parent_dict.keys())[row]
        child_pointer = (*index_pointer, row_key)
        try:
            child_pointer = self.my_index[child_pointer]
        except KeyError:
            self.my_index[child_pointer] = child_pointer
        index = self.createIndex(row, column, child_pointer)
        return index

    def get_row(self, key):
        if key:
            parent = key[:-1]
            if not parent:
                return 0
            return list(self.root[parent].keys()).index(key[-1])
        else:
            return 0

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        child_key_list = index.internalPointer()
        if child_key_list:
            parent_key_list = child_key_list[:-1]
            try:
                parent_key_list = self.my_index[parent_key_list]
            except KeyError:
                self.my_index[parent_key_list] = parent_key_list
            return self.createIndex(self.get_row(parent_key_list), 0,
                                    parent_key_list)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if parent.column() > 0:
            return 0    # only keys have children, not values
        if parent.isValid():
            indexPtr = parent.internalPointer()
            parentValue = self.root[indexPtr]
            if isinstance(parentValue, OrderedDict):
                return len(self.root[indexPtr])
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return len(self.root)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 2  # Key & value

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if role in (QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
            indexPtr = index.internalPointer()
            if index.column() == 1:    # Column 1, send the value
                return self.root[indexPtr]
            else:                   # Column 0, send the key
                if indexPtr:
                    return indexPtr[-1]
                else:
                    return None
        else:  # Not display or Edit
            return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        pointer = self.my_index[index.internalPointer()]
        self.root[pointer] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return 0
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = TupleKeyedOrderedDict(**{'1': OrderedDict({'sub': 'b'}), '2': OrderedDict({'subsub': '3'})})

    model = SettingsModel(data)
    tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    tree_view.setModel(model)
    tree_view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```